# a href onclick= doesnt work in all subpages

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in 9 subpages of a website, and in 7 of them the code works exactly as expected and as it should.
But on the other 2 pages it doesnt work, and i cant figure out the why.

```html
<div class="inner-offset darken-block">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s" id="filter">
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='07_services.html'">All services</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='systems_set-up.html'">SYSTEM-SET-UP</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='warehousing.html'">WAREHOUSING</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='pre-sales_management.html'">PRE SALES MANAGEMENT</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href onclick="location.href='pick_and_pack.html'">PICK & PACK</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='delivery.html'">DELIVERY</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='after_sales_management.html'">AFTER SALES MANAGEMENT</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='value_added_services.html'">VALUE ADDED SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='prices.php'">PREISE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code in the pages that doesn't work is the following:

```html
<div class="inner-offset darken-block">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s" id="filter">
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='07_services.html'">All services</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='systems_set-up.html'">SYSTEM-SET-UP</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='warehousing.html'">WAREHOUSING</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='pre-sales_management.html'">PRE SALES MANAGEMENT</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='pick_and_pack.html'">PICK & PACK</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='delivery.html'">DELIVERY</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href onclick="location.href='after_sales_management.html'">AFTER SALES MANAGEMENT</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='value_added_services.html'">VALUE ADDED SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href onclick="location.href='prices.php'">PREISE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

What doesnt work is the links. I click on the links when browsing the page and it doesnt respond to follow the link and load the page.

Comment: can you check console of your brwoser? is any error showing there?

Comment: Why are you using `href` without a value? Why are you `location.href` in JavaScript instead of just using the HTML `href` attribute properly?

Comment: @Fokrule 
The only thing i get in the console is:
theme.js:130 Uncaught TypeError: $container.imagesLoaded is not a function
    at Object.isotopeFilter (theme.js:130)
    at Object.build (theme.js:40)
    at Object.initialize (theme.js:21)
    at theme.js:239
    at theme.js:241

Comment: @Quentin because initially it hadn't worked to simply use the HTML "href" property and i was searching for a quick solution to solve this, and thats what i came up with and solved my task in 8/9 subpages i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are hypertext referencing using the `onclick` attribute. I would say use the `href` attribute. Like this:

```html
<div class="inner-offset darken-block">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s" id="filter">
      <li><a href="0.7_services.html">All services</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi Mwikala, 
Thank you for your reply. Well, i had used the "simple" <a href="0.7_services.html">All services</a> for making my links in the beginning but it wasn't working as it should, so i used the onclick attribute and it worked in all the other subpages. 
I tried your solution and it works in this page now. I should had thought myself to try this too. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try code like below:

```
<script >
    function jumpon(uri){
        document.location = "http://localhost/" + uri;
    }

</script>
<div class="inner-offset darken-block">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s" id="filter">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jumpon('07_services.html');">All services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jumpon('systems_set-up.html');">SYSTEM-SET-UP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jumpon('warehousing.html');">WAREHOUSING</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jumpon('pre-sales_management.html');">PRE SALES MANAGEMENT</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jumpon('pick_and_pack.html');">PICK & PACK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jumpon('delivery.html');">DELIVERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jumpon('after_sales_management.html');">AFTER SALES MANAGEMENT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jumpon('value_added_services.html');">VALUE ADDED SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:jumpon('prices.php');">PREISE</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s" id="filter">
          <li><a href="#" id="abc" onclick="func(); return false;">All services</a></li>
     </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function func()
      {
        document.getElementById("abc").href="service.html"; 
      }
    </script>
```